# Best way to move an internal pointer of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Consider my following array

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) $arr2test['a'.sprintf('%s',$i)]='arr # '.($i+1);
```

Now, I can access $arr2test by index. Like, I can echo $arr2test['a3'] to show the fourth element of this array.

My requirement is to get fifth element of this array. Let, I don't know the index of fifth element. I just know the fourth element index i.e. a3

I know I can do it by a foreach loop like code below -

```
$keyOfNextElement=null;
foreach($arr2test as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($a3Found)){
        $keyOfNextElement=$k;
        break;
    }
    if($k=='a3') $a3Found=true;
}
if(!is_null($keyOfNextElement)) echo arr2test[$keyOfNextElement];
else echo "Next element NOT found!!!";
```

Please consider a array that contain a lot of data like thousand or even more data.
So, in this case the above solution is not perfect one. Specially when I need to do such operation frequently.

Another note, I don't know weather its fourth or fifth element. I just know the index "a3" and I want the next element of "a3"

Comment: Why aren't you just using integers as indexes?

Comment: I'm not building that array, its coming from another process. So, index array is not available...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_keys()`.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr2test);
$index4 = array_search('a3', $keys);
$index5 = $keys[$index4+1];
$element5 = $arr2test[$index5];
```

Comment: You provide a nice trick. But not efficient I think. Its less efficient than my foreach loop solution.

Cause, you are building an array by keys first that means whole array is looping/reading. Then by array_search its read that position.

Comment: I don't think there's a more efficient way than your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$a4 = array_slice($arr2test, 4, 1);
```

Comment: man, I don't know the position. just I know the associative index. so, your solution is not acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a faster way to getting the index of fifth element

```
reset($arr2test);
for($j=1;$j<5;$j++){
    next($arr2test);
}
echo current($arr2test);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't know weather its fourth or fifth element. I just know the index "a3" and I want the next element of "a3". So, array pointer moving can't solve this problem :(